# Max of cluster_id in DBSCAN equals number of unique clusters or not

Tags: postgis, clustering

```
select count(distinct cluster_id) from rejected_dbscan 
union
select max(cluster_id) from rejected_dbscan
```

results in

```
8708
41128
```

Shouldn't the two values be equal? Does the max of cluster_id in DBSCAN equals number of unique clusters or not? It seems that cluster_id numbers have no relation to the actual number of clusters being formed.

Comment: You have answered the question: they are not equal. As of why, - without looking at the code -, I would say it keeps internal IDs of potential clusters that end up being dismissed (not enough points, merged to another cluster etc). Feel free to renumber the output :-)